# React js - pass values via Component and change Tab page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui

so I have the following problem.
I have a react page with tabs using Semantic UI tabs (https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/tab/).

The tabs look like the following:
all users | user details

in the 'all users' tab page, a table is created and filled with sql content. It contains a button for every player for more information.

If I click the button, I want:
 1. the tab changes to 'user details'
 2. the table button has an id, that should be passed to the second tab.

I'm a newbie and doesn't have any code to provide. 
I checked you can use a component and pass values by doing

Thank you in advance,
Doe

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of doing it

1. Store the currentTab, id in the component state.
       import React, { Component } from 'react'

   ```
       const TABS = {
         USERS: 'users',
         USER_DETAILS: 'userDetails'
       }

       class Users extends Component {
         state = {
           tab: TABS.USERS
           currentUserId: null
         }

         handleUserClick = (id) => {
           this.setState({ tab: TABS.USER_DETAILS, currentUserId: id })
         }

         render() {
           const { tab } = this.state

           if (tab.USER_DETAILS === TABS.USER_DETAILS && currentUserId) {
             return (
               ...
                 User Details UI
               ...
             )
           }

           return (
               ...
                 <Table>
                   ...
                     <td><button onClick={() => this.handleUserClick(id)} /></td>
                   ...
                 </Table>
               ...
             )
         }
       }
   ```

   2. If you are using react-router and can have a different page for each tab. (different URLs like `.../users` and `.../users/:id` for the user details.

      ```
      ...
      import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
      ...

      const usersPage = (props) => {
         return (
           <table>
            ...
              <td>
                <Linkto={{
                    pathname: `/users/${id}`,
                  }}
                />
            ...
           </table>

         )
       }

      // user details page, use can use the useHistory hook from the react-router but for bravity I will just refer to the history
      const userDetailsPage = (props) => {
        ...
        const { match } = props
        const { id } = match.params.id
        ...
      }
      ...
      ```